# Flutter FirebaseAnimatedList query is not working properly

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

I tried to fetch some data from the firebase realtime database using a `FirebaseAnimatedList()` using a search query which should be `query : ref.child("users").child(userPath).orderByChild("id").equalTo(userID)` but instead of that query works without second child like this`query : ref.child("users").orderByChild("id").equalTo(userID)`

And it seems like when data is passed `.equalTo(userID)` if passed userID is not found in the database it loads a blank container I'm looking for a way to avoid loading a blank container and return a custom view if there's no value that matches `.equalTo(userID)`

realtime database example :

```
{
  "users" : {
    "user1" : {
      "lname" : "dee",
      "id" : "12"
    },
    "user2" : {
      "lname" : "nee",
      "id" : "13"
    },
    "user3" : {
      "lname" : "lee",
      "id" : "14"
    },
    "user4" : {
      "lname" : "bree",
      "id" : "15"
    }
  }
```

Code :

```
FirebaseAnimatedList(
        query: ref.child("users").orderByChild("id").equalTo(this.userid),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
            Animation<double> animation, int index) {
          return SizeTransition(
            sizeFactor: animation,
            axis: Axis.horizontal,
            axisAlignment: -0.8,
            child: Column(
              textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
              verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 100.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  "User ID : " + snapshot.value["id"],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50.0,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }));
```

Answer (score 0):

The query is actually correct, to be able to access the `id` using `orderByChild("id")`, you dont need to use another `child()` method.

> I'm looking for a way to avoid loading a blank container and return a custom view

```
FirebaseAnimatedList(
        query: ref.child("users").orderByChild("id").equalTo(this.userid),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
            Animation<double> animation, int index) {
         if(snapshot.value != null){
          return SizeTransition(
            sizeFactor: animation,
            axis: Axis.horizontal,
            axisAlignment: -0.8,
            child: Column(
              textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
              verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 100.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  "User ID : " + snapshot.value["id"],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50.0,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
         }
         else{
             return Text("no Data");
            }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }));
```

Comment: thank you so much for the response but it does not work when ```.equalTo(this.userid)``` don't match database ```"id"```

Comment: u have `id : 12`, is `this.userid` equal to the authenticated user id? If so then sure it wont work... you should do `.equalTo("12")`, or add the user authenticated id instead